# Looking for ASP.NET(MVC, AJAX) Image Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-ajax

Anybody help, I need Image Manager with multi-upload, crop, resize....
And final cost less $150.
Maybe somebody using this perfect solution - I want too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the one at [Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ImageGalleryImageManager.aspx)

It does what you are asking about. It's not as polished as some out there but it does seem easy enough to use and extend.

Answer (score 0):

There are good jQuery plugins for that .

Please try some of these :

www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop
www.visual-blast.com/.../jcrop-jquery-image-crop-plugin
www.noupe.com/.../45-fresh-out-of-the-oven-jquery-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

The MvcCmsSocial area in the MvcCms project under 2.0 in the source at http://mvccms.codeplex.com/ has an mvc based solution for this.  Right now it only does upload and crop but more may be added.  If you feel industrious add the extras as a patch or join the project and check it in.